# Selective disablement of certain cells for data entry during run time

Tags: excel, vba

From the picture below, all of the data being displayed is populated at run time. Nothing in range E is input at run time, however, I want to write a piece of code in the module that will disable/clear contents of the cells highlighted in yellow. I would **only** know the row number at run time though. For example, I would know that row 4 will need to have cell E4 disabled for any offline data entry. I have a piece of code that disables the whole range but I only want selective cells to not accept text. I want all cells under E, except E4, E7, E10, E17 and E20, to be able to accept input. Thanks in advance for your help!

[image]

**Code:**

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Not Intersect(Range("E1:E10"), Target) Is Nothing Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Target.ClearContents  
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End If
End Sub
```

*** Adding Additional screen grabs to help w/ the run time error ***

When the control hits the breakpoint below, it gets transferred to the code written in the Sheet.

[image]

Error encountered here.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Range("E1:E10"), Target) Is Nothing Then
       'If Target.Offset(0, -2).Value = "" Then ' 1st check - e.g. C4 is empty OR
        If Target.Offset(0, -3).Value Like "*stor*" Then ' 2nd check - e.g. B4 contains "*stor*"
            ' let the user change this cell
        Else
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            Target.ClearContents
            Application.EnableEvents = True
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: But, like I mentioned in my post, I would not know the exact addresses like E4, E7, E17... before hand. Those will be cells that become available for "non-edit" at run time.

Comment: What kind of property will distinguish these cells, will it be a yellow background color ? If Yes, you may check every cell inside the range, e.g. `If Target.Interior.Color = vbYellow Then ....`

Comment: Good question, let me elaborate. So, I am fetching data from a database called "JIRA" (more like an Agile life cycle management tool) and I write that data to excel. When the code writes in column B (e.g., B4, B7 etc.,), at the same time, I want the respective E cells (E4, E7 etc.,) to be un-editable. Hope that clarifies a bit.

Comment: It means you could allow to change in these rows, where column C is empty or column B contains "*stor*". I've re edit my code sample already (besize I'm Jira user too).

Comment: Awesome! Let me check and report.

Comment: Actually, after reviewing your code, when column C contains "stor", I DO NOT want the user to edit the corresponding E cell. So, should I copy everything in you else condition to If condition?

Comment: Yes. Of course. You decide what the code will do depends on if and else condition.

Comment: I am encountering a Run Time 1004 error: Application Defined or object defined error. See additional pictures attached to my question for understanding.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, should be `If Target.Offset(0, -3).Value`. Already edited my code.